# Prevent a TreeView from firing events in VB6?

Tags: events, vb6, treeview

In some VB6 code, I have a handler for a TreeView's Collapse event:

```
Private Sub MyTree_Collapse(ByVal Node as MSComCtlLib.Node)
```

This is called whenever a node in the tree is collapsed, whether by the user or programmatically.  As it turns out, through some roundabout execution, it may happen that this handler will wind up telling a node to collapse, leading to infinite recursion.

I can think of multiple ways to skin this cat, but what seems simplest to me is to tell the TreeView not to raise events for some period of time.  I can't find a simple call to let me do this, though.  Has anyone successfully done this, or do I need to keep track of state in some other manner so I can respond appropriately when recursive events come along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that like many events in VB, it can't be switched off.

Just set a boolean flag as you've suggested.

Answer (score 3):

@Phil - I came to the same conclusion.  My implementation of `MyTree_Collapse` now looks something like this (where `m_bHandlingCallback` is a member variable):

```
Private Sub MyTree_Collapse(ByVal Node as MSComCtlLib.Node)
    If m_bHandlingCallback Then Exit Sub

    m_bHandlingCallback = True
    DoSomeStuff
    m_bHandlingCallback = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way in VB6 is to have an alternate `WithEvents` reference to the control:

```
Private WithEvents alt as TreeView
```

and in `Form_Load`:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Set alt = MyTree
End Sub
```

Now `alt` will receive lots of events like this:

```
Private Sub alt_Collapse(ByVal Node as MSComCtlLib.Node)
Set alt = Nothing
'DoSomeStuff'
Set alt = MyTree
End Sub
```

But, during the `DoSomeStuff`, the events are unhooked - which also applies to all other event `Sub`s for `alt` without the need for them to have intrusive changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the flag variable as STATIC in the Sub.  This avoids making the variable global and makes it keep its value between calls.

Comment: Is a function static variable in VB shared across all instances of a class, like it is in C++?  I went with member data (not global data) so that setting the flag wouldn't affect _all_ instances of my class - just the one I cared about.